# How to create routes with different authentication for all API methods

Tags: api, authentication, routes, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a web API project, based on ASP .NET core 2.2.
This API project uses JWT authentication.
Now I need to make it possible to authenticate not only with the previous JWT authentication, but also with AzureADB2C JWT Token.
The same controllers and methods can be accessed regardless of the authentication method used.

This is how I currently implemented the functionality

```
var defaultSchemes = new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme };
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(defaultSchemes)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

services
    .AddAuthentication()
    //.AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options)); <-- this works only if it is placed before the AddJwtBearer method, I don't understand why
    .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        })
    .AddJwtBearer(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme, configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.Authority = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"] + Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"] + "/" + Configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"] + "/v2.0";
            configureOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];               
        });
```

This works, but not exactly as I would like.
In fact, the token passed in the request is validated with both authentication methods, with the result that in the file log, for each api method called, one of the 2 authentication methods produces an validation error.

I would like to have 2 endpoints for all the api methods, one that uses standard JWT authentication, and the other that uses the AzureADB2C.

Example:

http://apiurl/culture/jwt/controller/action --> for standard JWT authentication
http://apiurl/culture/b2c/controller/action --> for ADB2c authentication

or

http://apiurl/jwt/culture/controller/action --> for standard JWT authentication
http://apiurl/b2c/culture/controller/action --> for ADB2c authentication

How can I do this or what is the best way to make these 2 authentication methods coexist for all APIs?

**edit:** I found this similar question with a valid answer: [Path based authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565243/path-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core-mvc-2-0)
In addition to the solution given in the answer, I added this class for not edit the route of each controller.

```
public class AuthenticationConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        var authenticationPrefix = new AttributeRouteModel(new RouteAttribute("{authentication}"));

        foreach (var controller in application.Controllers)
        {
            var matchedSelectors = controller.Selectors.Where(x => x.AttributeRouteModel != null).ToList();
            if (matchedSelectors.Any())
            {
                foreach (var selectorModel in matchedSelectors)
                {
                    selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel = AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(authenticationPrefix, selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel);
                }
            }

            var unmatchedSelectors = controller.Selectors.Where(x => x.AttributeRouteModel == null).ToList();
            if (unmatchedSelectors.Any())
            {
                foreach (var selectorModel in unmatchedSelectors)
                {
                    selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel = authenticationPrefix;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in ConfigureService method in Startup.cs

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    // Set the authentication and culture convention for all controllers, so you do not have to specify in the route for each controller
    config.Conventions.Insert(0, new LocalizationConvention());
    config.Conventions.Insert(1, new AuthenticationConvention());
    // -----Authorization filter
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Is there a better way to do what I need?

Furthermore, I still don't understand why, using this code it works:

```
services
.AddAuthentication()
.AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))
.AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
    {
        configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
        configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
    });
```

but whit this, ADB2C authentication doesn't work:

```
services
.AddAuthentication()    
.AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
    {
        configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
        configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
    })
.AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

Comment: Do you have to have two endpoints for each controller?

Comment: Yes, but making sure that each endpoint uses a specific authentication.
And preferably, I would like to avoid having to edit each controller, if possible.